# How to Use the Google.GData.Contacts Version 3

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-api, google-contacts-api

I have implemented the application to read all the google contacts. The application was done by a .NET Core. I have used the Google.GData.Contacts(Version 2.2.0) Nuget package to read all the contacts. My application always show some warning messages like below

[image]

As per this document https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3, I believe the version 3.0 is there. But, I'm not sure how to include or use it.

It would be much appreciated if anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There hasnt been any development on the GData library in years [gdata](https://github.com/google/google-gdata/tree/master/clients/cs).  So I dont think its going to work with .net core.

This is due to the fact that most of the gdata apis have been shut down by now [gdata](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory).

As you can see from the nuget page [Google.GData.Contacts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.Contacts/)  the last update was 6/25/2013  which is before the release date of .net core.

What you should consider doing is checking the [google people api](https://developers.google.com/people) which should contain similar response and supports the Google .net client library.

[Install-Package Google.Apis.People.v1 -Version 1.25.0.830](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.People.v1/)

## It is still live

The google contacts api is still live so you can use it if you like you will just have to create your own system to access the endpoints.  As google has no library that works with .net core for gdata.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for your suggestion DalmTo. I will check with your suggestion. Thanks again.